# Open new UIView when select a row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem that is proving difficult to resolve.

I should open a new `UITableView` when clicked a cell in the table above.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ChoiceChampionViewController *choiceChampionViewController = [[ChoiceChampionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChoiceChampionViewController" bundle:nil];

NSString * ind = @".....";
NSString * number = ..;
ind = [ind stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"XX" withString:number];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:number forKey:@"Region"];
choiceChampionViewController.url = ind;
[self.view addSubview: choiceChampionViewController.view];
}
```

**ChoiceChampionViewController** is structured as follows:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {        
        champion = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Here is some text to make the navBar big";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
   Method for process data
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [champion count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    League * app = [[League alloc] init];
    app = [champion objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = app.title;

    return cell;
}
```

But it keeps giving me this error:
[ChoiceChampionViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance.
Can we help me?

Comment: I think you release object in somewhere . Please check it

Comment: can you check "champion" array contains objects or not?

Comment: I use ARC. The "champion" array, have fifty object.

Comment: I have tried with new UIView. If the View is empty, no error, but if i insert a table view, when i clicked on the screen, i have this error: [NewViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Answer (score 0):

open that new `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` with use of `pushViewController` for go in to new `UIViewController` like bellow...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{

    ChoiceChampionViewController * choiceChampionViewController = [[ChoiceChampionViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChoiceChampionViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
    [_backButton release],
    _backButton = nil;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:choiceChampionViewController animated:YES];
    [choiceChampionViewController release];
}
```

**UPDATE :**

also use this bellow structure for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    League * app = [[League alloc] init];
    app = [champion objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = app.title;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: nothing happens. I press on the table but does not change view.
This is a setting view that it show only at once when the application is first launched.
In my AppDelegate, the first view is so called:
ChoiceViewController *settingsVC = [[ChoiceViewController alloc] init];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: settingsVC animated: YES completion:^{}

My navigationController is nil

Comment: thats why its not pushed to new controller , in appdelegate for rootViewController set it with `UINavigationBarController` like this         `    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

Comment: But in my AppDelegate, the rootViewController is
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
because my app have one tabbar.

Comment: also i update answer it may be crashed because not use proper format of `UITableViewCell` allocation ..

Comment: when i push the first table, when the second table load, i have the error. I have tried with breakpoints but it's impossible to understand when the error occurred.

Comment: Yes, but the error is the same. I use ARC. But I do not think it is important.

Comment: here in `property` use `strong` instead of `retain` like `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrMember;` and then let me know.. do this if you used it and declare this type of any object in .h file

Comment: Nothing. When i call reload data in fetchedData, the program check numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and it go to error.

Comment: it means here not data available in the champion array or its nil so crashed here